# Jmeter - concurrency and events generation

Tags: jmeter

I have a data model JSON object which has 900 events sampling at 1-second intervals. I have to split these 900 events into 60 events fragments, send 60 events at particular reps once these 60 are done next 60 should be sent for the same users.
how can I achieve do I need multiple concurrent thread?

Answer (score 0):

1. For sending data in chunks of 60 "events" you can use [Synchronizing Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68478223/jmeter-timestamp-in-jssrpreprocessor-is-same-for-multiple-requests/68479830#68479830) with "Number of Simulated Users to Group by" set to `60` and a [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) with 60 threads (virtual users)
2. For extracting data out of the JSON data model you can use HTTP Request sampler with `file` protocol like:

   [image]

   it will return the full content of your "data model" file as the response and you should be able to extract "events" using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor)

Comment: Apologies for My previous question if it's not clear. I have 900 events in a JSON model. I have to take 60 events fragments from the JSON and post it to 150 users per second. then next 60 events till 900 is done. once that is done. I will be generating, new 900 events and posting the 60 events fragment in each transaction for different users?.

Comment: using a file protocol  and HTTP request Sampler would I be able to generate time while sending this JSON for e.g I  have a Json field data model "eventtime" which is incremented every second within the datamodel ( these occur as { {
  "events": [ {
      "tripModel": {
 "ignitionONTime": 1626793529992,
        "ignitionStatus": "ON"
      },
 "eventDateTime": 1626793529992
    }, 
      {
      "tripModel": {
  "ignitionONTime": 1626793529992,
        "ignitionStatus": "ON"
      },
 "eventDateTime": 1626793530992
    }
    ]}: eventDateTime is incremented in each event .

Comment: is the Synchronizing Timer right link since its goes into stack overflow question which is not related to this question.