# Jmeter timestamp in jssrpreprocessor is same for multiple requests

Tags: jmeter

We have script, jssr preprocess which will copy the file from one bucket and paste it to another bucket in Amazon s3and http request which will take the file and do further processing.
Before copying file we do renaming filename with timestamp(function help builder). Everytime we do performance testing it has to pick unique file name.

But when I run send requests for 5 minutes, timestamp remain same, it's taking first timestamp through there is some second difference between each request. Is there any way each request to generate unique timestamp within jssr preprocessor

Answer (score 0):

It's not very possible to come up with the solution without seeing your "script".

Blind shot: if you're using [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) inside the JSR223 PreProcessor only first occurrence will be evaluated, on subsequent executions the same value will be used.

If this is the case either move the `__time()` function to the Parameters input field or use [System.currentTimeMillis()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) function instead

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JSR223 Sampler Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank you DMitri, I tried below   inc = ${increment}
long number = Long.parseLong(vars.get("MyNumber"))
number = number + inc +${__Random(100,100000,)}
vars.put("MyNumber", String.valueOf(number))
log.info("Current number is ***************->"+(vars.get("MyNumber")));


2021-07-22 11:48:21,940 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 PreProcessor-Replacewith: Current number is ***************->7900001745
2021-07-22 11:48:25,708 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 PreProcessor-Replacewith: Current number is ***************->7900022761

Comment: What's unclear in my answer? If you prefer copying and pasting instead of thinking - change your `${increment}` to `vars.get('increment') as long` and  `${__Random(100,100000,)}` to `org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextLong(100,100000)`. More information: [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter)